# Combine SELECTing a record with COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I have this MySQL query here which works GREAT! There is one extra thing I need to do though. Currently, it is returning the highest percentage back. The highest percentage is based on the amount of occurrences that a particular record type has been generated in the database on a particular date. What I want it to do is also return the **name** of the associated record that has this high percentage. I've tried incorporating it into the query below but it seems to be always failing. Any advice on this would be awesome.

```
SELECT *, COALESCE((acknowledged / generated), 0) AS result
FROM    (
    SELECT  (
        SELECT      COUNT(*)
        FROM        logs
        INNER JOIN  generated_logs
        ON          generated_logs.log_fk = logs.log_pk 
        WHERE       logs.department_fk = ?
        AND         DATE(generated_logs.generated_time) = ?
    ) AS generated, (
    SELECT      COUNT(generated_logs.log_fk) AS magnitude 
    FROM        logs
    INNER JOIN  generated_logs
    ON          generated_logs.log_fk = logs.log_pk
    WHERE       logs.department_fk = ?
    AND         generated_logs.acknowledged = 1
    AND         DATE(generated_logs.generated_time) = ?
    GROUP BY    generated_logs.log_fk
    ORDER BY    magnitude DESC
    LIMIT 1         
    ) AS acknowledged ) AS result
```

**Current output is:**

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+
| Generated | Acknowledged | Result |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
|     6     |       3      |  0.50  |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
```

**What I need is:**

```
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
| Generated | Acknowledged | Result |   Name   |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
|     6     |       3      |  0.50  | Test Log |
+-----------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

The **name** is a field in the **logs** table.

Comment: can you provide the sql fiddle with the data so it will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more try ...

```
SELECT *, COALESCE((a.magnitude / g.generated), 0) AS result
   FROM
       (
           SELECT      COUNT(*) AS generated
           FROM        logs
           INNER JOIN  generated_logs
           ON          generated_logs.log_fk = logs.log_pk 
           WHERE       logs.department_fk = ?
           AND         DATE(generated_logs.generated_time) = ?
       ) AS g,
       (
            SELECT COUNT(generated_logs.log_fk) AS magnitude, logs.name
            FROM        logs
            INNER JOIN  generated_logs
            ON          generated_logs.log_fk = logs.log_pk
            WHERE       logs.department_fk = ?
            AND         generated_logs.acknowledged = 1
            AND         DATE(generated_logs.generated_time) = ?
            GROUP BY    generated_logs.log_fk
            ORDER BY    magnitude DESC
            LIMIT 1 
       ) AS a
```

Comment: try again, this is hard to debug for you, if this doesn't work you will need to put everything into http://sqlfiddle.com/ so i can help further

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working exactly as expected. Oh, and sorry, I shall use that next time.